# How to capture a parameter in an response url in Angular (Stripe Connect)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

The first step in setting up [Stripe Connect (standalone account)](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standalone-accounts) is to ask the user permission, thus connecting the user.

This can be achieved by visting the url:

```
https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=[MY-CLIENT-ID]&scope=read_write
```

After the user has granted permission, the user will be redirected to an url of reference with parameters in it:

```
my.urlofreference.com/#!/page/account?scope=read_write&code=[AN-ACCESS_CODE]
```

Now my question is, how I can capture this `[AN-ACCESS-CODE]` when the user 
visits my redirect url `my.urlofreference.com/#!/page/account`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why are you returning to an angular route and not a server side one? Exposing codes in browser is not very secure

Comment: Ah it should be server side??

Comment: Your redirect_uri, a page on your website to which the user will be redirected after connecting their account (or failing to, should that be the case), set by you.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using angular-ui-router You can get it by `$state.params.code`